# How to assign a variable to an element in Javascript like in Actionscript?

Tags: javascript, actionscript

In Actionscript I can do

```
var thing:MovieClip = new MovieClip ();
thing.somevar = 1;
```

and the thing object would have a variable called somevar.

Can I do the same in Javascript if I created an element using createElement?

Comment: Just curious, but why do you need to assign a variable to an element in JavaScript?

Comment: He means, "add a property to an element" (or "object").

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you'd be creating a custom/unsupported attribute for the HTML element that you can read back. Most people will say that it's not good practice but it does work on all browsers*.

Be careful though to avoid circular references. IE cannot free the memory used by objects with circular references if one of the object is an HTML element. This will result in memory leak on IE. Though other browsers can handle it well enough.

** At least all browsers I've ever tried.*

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
var a = document.createElement("input");
alert(a.localName); // gets "input"
```